# Two separate breakers for one 240v appliance?

Tags: electrical-panel

I have what seems to be an unusual wiring situation for an old 240v baseboard heater and thermostat that I am replacing.  One of the hot sides to the heater thermostat is on a 120 breaker and the other hot is from one side of a separate 240 double breaker for the microwave. Besides being what I would consider unusual, will this work correctly and more importantly, is it safe?  And maybe this is why the old heater never worked?

I’m comfortable replacing these items but if the wiring should be corrected at the panel I’ll call in a pro.

Comment: What make and model is the panel in question?

Comment: Is your microwave oven on a 2-pole 240 V breaker? What amperage rating? Is this in the USA?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, when you see a janky mess like that, remove it immediately.  Single circuits shouldn't bridge two breakers, with one exception.

You have to look at the ampere requirements for both the microwave and the heater.  Heaters need circuit breaker capacity of 125% of the heater's requirement.  If that is within the circuit breaker's rating, it may be appropriate to have both on the same breaker.

A 240V-only load needs either a 2-pole breaker, or two adjacent, matching breakers which are tied with a listed handle tie.

Answer (score 1):

The two hots for the 240 V baseboard heater should be in the two sides of one 2-pole common trip breaker of the correct amperage rating.

The arrangement you have now is completely unacceptable. It may be the reason that the heater does not work. It could be that the two hots are on the same leg so that there is zero voltage between them.

Comment: Thanks guys. I think that’s what I needed to hear as it just didn’t pass the smell test. I’m in Massachusetts and It’s a 2 pole Type MP-T,  10,000 120/240 VAC

Comment: I’m not that comfortable playing around in the panel so l

Comment: Will call in a pro. Your answers are much appreciated!